# How to get full list of apps in play-store

Tags: google-play-store

Is there a way to get a list with all the apps in google play?

And if so is there a way to find the SDK from any app created there?

Comment: There are several hundred thousand apps in the Play Store, with more added every day. Not to mention the device, carrier, and location restrictions which will make your list different than mine. As for getting the SDK, do you mean APK? If so, there's been at least one question on here on how to get the APK of an app from the Play Store. Search around a bit. It would help us to help you if we knew what sort of problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

As of [June 27th, 2012](http://techcrunch.com/2012/06/27/google-play/) Google has announced over 600,000 app in the Google Play. Now, if you want the whole list at once, you should ask Google for it. I'm sure that based on regulations and privacy laws they won't give it to you. As Al Everett said, they are many more added each day as well as removed. I personally have just removed 2 of my apps from the store 2 days ago. So the list will only be valid at the moment it's generated.

As for the SDK... Download it from [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) site. Unless you're looking for an [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29).