# List all free application on google play

Tags: google-play-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get full list of apps in play-store](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32046/how-to-get-full-list-of-apps-in-play-store)

Is there a way I can get list of all free apps on Google Play.
Normally only 24 apps are displayed on one web page.Something like list view instead of icon view.Also do we have a tag search option?Ex search for *device tracking apps*

Answer (score 0):

Basically no.
As +RyanConrad said there are far too many free apps, which change constantly, to be listed on a single page.  If there are ~600,000 apps and an html link to an app was around 150 characters, and each character is 8 bits, that's ~85 megs just to get the full listing.  I don't know for sure, but I don't think your web browser will like trying to render that page.